# a problem with a mapping ( map enter and tab key)

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

I have this mapping in my vimrc:

```
imap <expr> <silent> <cr> neocomplete#mappings#close_popup() .
\ "<Plug>(neosnippet_jump_or_expand)"
```

and it's working great. When I press enter in a neocomplete popup it expands neosnippet but the problem is that `<cr>` will now work only for that and will not do a return line in insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your question *could* be more elaborate. Perhaps you need something like:

```
imap <expr> <silent> <cr> neosnippet#expandable_or_jumpable() ?
            \ "<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)" :
            \ neocomplete#mappings#close_popup()."\<CR>"
```

Comment: thats work in the case of function has a paramettre , but in the case of the function hase no paramettre it insert    obg.fun()()      it insert () two times

Comment: What function? Snippet?

Comment: plz look at :   https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues/461    you will understand  the problem

Comment: i use neosnnipet with neocomplete  for autocompletion  ,  when i chose the function to autocomplete neosnippet generate automaticly a snippet to insert all function prototype

Comment: I will give you my advice: *DON'T* use the same key for autocompletion and snippet expansion. Use `<C-j>` for snippets.

Comment: yeah but it will be cool , with that we can have vim autocompletion like ide

Comment: If you use the same key, Vim won't know when you want to autocomplete only, or to autocomplete *and* expand snippet. You either have to use another key, OR use a 2-step process (press Enter once to complete and close popup, press Enter again to expand snippet, if you want) -> the 1st method is faster. You should at least use Tab for some of that functionality, instead of Enter.

Comment: no vim autocomplete and expand at the same time that work for me  , the problem is when i map < cr> key  thatswork for autocomplete and expand at the same time , but with that < cr> key will not work in insert mode for returning into new line

Answer (score 0):

This is the how complex insert mode mappings that involve the popup menu are usually written:

```
iemap <expr> <key> pumvisible() ? "\<another-key>" : "\<key>"
```

The ternary operator is used to "press" `<another-key>` if we are in a popup menu or `<key>` if we are not.

Assuming the snippet in your question works (I don't use those plugins), the following mapping should expand the selected snippet if you are in a popup menu or just "press" a regular `<CR>` otherwise.

```
imap <expr> <silent> <cr> pumvisible() ?
    \ neocomplete#mappings#close_popup() . "<Plug>(neosnippet_jump_or_expand)" :
    \ "\<CR>"
```

---

Note that the code above doesn't check if it is in a *neobundle + neosnippet* popup menu so I'd suggest putting all that in a function so that you have some elbow room for all your checks (and get a chance to use an actual `if-elseif-else-endif` conditional instead of a deep ternary operator.

Comment: thats work but there is one last problem look plz here at the end : https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues/461